# Create redirect from url like www.example.us/?p=100&option=

Tags: htaccess, redirects

I am switching CMS and have about 600 URLs that need to get redirected to the new scheme. The URL on the old site looks like the following on my test server:

```
www.example.us/?p=100&option=com_wordpress&Itemid=619
```

The new URL scheme will exist as:

```
www.example.us/blog.php?p=100
```

Some old URLs use p=, others id= or catid=. I have tried various redirects like the following, all failing for various reasons:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^p=100
RewriteRule .* 100.php
```

The result is that it redirect to 100.php but appends the query string to the url and ends up like:

```
example.us/100.php?p=100&option=com_wordpress&Itemid=619
```

That is the closest to a solution. I have also tried the following with the failure message noted below:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^p=100
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ 100.php
# Fails as it appends query string

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^p=100
RewriteRule .* 100.php$
# Fails with The requested URL /100.php$ was not found on this server.

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^p=100$
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ 100.php [L,R=301]
# Fails redirecting to /index.html

RewriteRule p=100 100.php  [R=301,L]
# Fails redirecting to /index.html

RewriteRule ^p=100$ 100.php  [R=301,L]
# Fails redirecting to /index.html
```

I tried many of the above with/without http:// preceding the redirect to URL.

Comment: Is there are relationship between the old and new URLs? Your example code seems to suggest that `/p=NNN` maps to `NNN.php` - however, this does not correlate to the URL example at the top (where `p=100` seems to map to `blog.php?p=2792`)? Is `p=NNN` (or `id=` or `catid=`) the only part of the old URL that matters?

Comment: My apologies. The 2792 should have been switched to 100. I just corrected it. So yes the $id or $p or $catid is the relationship. The goal is to redirect to a simple URL like 100.php, but without the additional parameters baggage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This assumes that `p`, `id` or `catid` always appears at the start of the query string, and that the value of this parameter is the "file" basename in the new URL, as per your code examples.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(p|id|catid)=(\d+)
RewriteRule ^$ /%2.php? [R=301,L]
```

The `^$` pattern only processes requests for the document root (ie. `example.com/`). The `%2` back reference refers to the 2nd parenthesised sub pattern in the CondPattern (ie. `(\d+)`). If you omit the `R` flag (and don't specify an absolute URL) then it will result in an internal rewrite, not an external redirect as I would assume is required here (ie. the URL in the address bar would not change).

The `?` on the end of the `RewriteRule` substitution strips the original query string from the rewritten URL. This essentially creates an "empty" query string (the `?` is not present in the result). Alternatively you can use the `QSD` (Query String Discard) flag on Apache 2.4+

By default, unless you specify a new query string on the `RewriteRule` substitution then the original query string will be copied onto the rewritten URL (as you have found). If you ever wanted to *merge* the original query string with a new one that you specify then you would need to use the `QSA` (Query String Append) flag.

Comment: I had to tweak my id name and final URLs, but with your help I have it working for both the category and individual blogs which follow the pattern of being at the beginning of the string. Fantastic. I separated the rule to a separate line for the ID and tweaked it to no avail. That line/pattern looks like `index.php/archived-content?id=248`, with id=$n at the end. I have about a dozen of these and they will get redirected to completely custom URLs, such as funny-business.php, no relation to the ID. My tweaks are not getting a match.

Comment: Glad you got it working (the first part at least). If this sufficiently answered the question then please mark it as _accepted_ (click the "tick" on the left) to remove it from the unanswered question queue. Please feel free to ask another question regarding your other redirects/regex.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out how to solve the second part of the question where the ID= was found at the end like the following:

```
example.com/index.php/archived-content?id=206
```

by adding a line to the .htaccess like:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=206
RewriteRule (.*) /some-file-name.php? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Small tip: You don't need the parenthesis around the `RewriteRule` pattern unless you are using a backreference (eg. `$1`) in the substitution. ie. `(.*)` is the same as `.*`.